# How do I enable Rails i18n fallbacks only for some locales, not all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4, fallback, rails-i18n

I am using i18n fallbacks in a Rails 4 application in order to reduce duplicate translations for "de" and "de-AT" locales (possibly more pairs like this to add in the future). In order to make this possible, I've enabled fallbacks in my `application.rb`:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'de-AT' => 'de'}
```

But I don't want other locales to fall back to English (which is the default locale), neither in production nor in development.

Is that possible, and if yes, how do I achieve that?

Comment: So you want the application to show the I18n keys instead? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, that's how it was before adding the 'de-AT' locale. We only added fallback to DRY our translations.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? We'd like to have 'en_au' and 'en_us' fallback to 'en', but have no fallback for 'fr_fr'.

Comment: unfortunately I had to go with everything falling back to `en`. The reason I didn't want to do that initially is because I thought it's harder to spot whenever there is a missing translation. It is true, however we have not had any big issues regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky in Rails up to 6.1 because you need to [beat the logic in the Railtie initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e300f1121dd24204cf0586521f34632485fce15/activesupport/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb#L92) which desperately wants to fallback to the `default_locale`.

To set the default fallback locale to `nil` you need to use the following code:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks.defaults = [[]] # If you just write [], then default_locale is used
config.i18n.fallbacks.map = {
  ca: :es, # Catalan fallback to Spanish
  de: "en-UK", # German fallback to UK English first, then automatically to :en
}
```

Note #1: By default all country variants (`en-US`) will fallback to languages first (e.g `en`) and you only need to specify something if you want to fallback differently.

Note #2: To check if you set it up correctly:

```
...> rails console
2.7.2 :001 > I18n.fallbacks["de-AT"] # Check what happens with Austrian German?
 => [:"de-AT", :de, :"en-UK", :en]

2.7.2 :002 > I18n.fallbacks[:ca]     # Catalan falls back to Spanish
 => [:es]

2.7.2 :003 > I18n.fallbacks[:fr]     # French should have no fallback!
 => [:fr]
```

Note #3: Mappings will be recursively expanded.

```
config.i18n.fallbacks.map = {
  es: :fr, # Spanish to French
  fr: :en, # French to English
}

rails console
2.7.2 :001 > I18n.fallbacks[:es]
 => [:es, :fr, :en]
```

But you don't need to watch for cycles and/or duplicates. These are filtered out.

Note #4: The mapping hash can map language codes also to arrays, which are processed in order from left to right.

```
config.i18n.fallbacks.map = {
  ca: [:es, :fr, :en], # Catalan falls back to Spanish then French, then English
}
```

Note #5: I haven't found a good canonical language mapping model, which takes "appropriate" fallback decisions based on language current language skills per country and encodes it in Rails.

Note #6: I would strongly suggest:

- Use :en as the only and primary fallback for everything.
- Keep the :en version as simple and un-idiomatic as possible.
- Customize for "en-US" and "en-UK" in select places.
- If you do translate, do it comprehensively. It is very irritating to have partially translated UI.

Note #7: Starting in Rails 6.1.3 the default locale is no longer included by default as a fallback ([see this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4bd56f44280b645aebe9192db5862d4529cc0999))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing default locale?

Where ever you have

```
I18n.locale = :somelocale
```

Try adding

```
I18n.default_locale = :somelocale
```