# i18n fallbacks, but only those explicitly stated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

My config/initializers/i18n.rb file

```
require "i18n/backend/fallbacks"                                                                                                                                            
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)                                                                                                              
I18n.fallbacks.map(:'en-US' => :en, :'fr-FR' => :fr, :'de-DE' => :de, :'es-ES' => :es, :'zh-CN' => :zh)
```

but right now missing stuff in french will fallback on English which isn't desired behavior. How can I have specific fallbacks for specific locales only?

Comment: What is the desired behavior for missing French translations?

Comment: Basically if they are missing they are missing  - right now it displays English

Comment: So, you want nothing to be displayed -- just empty?

Comment: missing translation, basically

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with an approach that overloaded all the methods to handle what I wanted exactly. I still hope there's something more straight-forward out there, but this is what I was able to get working.

app/helpers/i18n_helper.rb

```
module I18nHelper
  def translate(key, options={})
    mapping = MyApp::Application.config.locale_mapping
    super(key, options.merge(raise: true))
  rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
    if mapping.has_key?(locale)
      super(key, options.merge(locale: mapping[locale]))
    else
      super(key, options)
    end
  end
  alias :t :translate
end
```

config/initializers/i18n.rb

```
module I18n
  class CustomFallbackExceptionHandler < ExceptionHandler
    def call(exception, locale, key, options)
      mapping = MyApp::Application.config.locale_mapping
      if mapping.has_key? locale
        I18n.t(key, options.merge(locale: mapping[locale]))
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

I18n.exception_handler = I18n::CustomFallbackExceptionHandler.new
```

config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:'en-US', :'fr-FR', :'de-DE', :'es-ES', :'zh-CN', :en, :fr, :de, :es, :zh]
config.locale_mapping = {:'en-US' => :en, :'fr-FR' => :fr, :'de-DE' => :de, :'es-ES' => :es, :'zh-CN' => :zh}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky in Rails up to 6.1 because you need to [beat the logic in the Railtie initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e300f1121dd24204cf0586521f34632485fce15/activesupport/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb#L92) which desperately wants to fallback to the `default_locale`.

To set the default fallback locale to `nil` you need to use the following code:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks.defaults = [[]] # If you just write [], then default_locale is used
config.i18n.fallbacks.map = {
  :'en-US' => :en, 
  :'fr-FR' => :fr, 
  :'de-DE' => :de, 
  :'es-ES' => :es, 
  :'zh-CN' => :zh,
}
```

Note #1: By default all country variants (e.g. `en-US`) will fallback to languages first (e.g `en`) and you only need to specify something if you want to fallback differently. So essentially your mapping could be simplified like this:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks.defaults = [[]] 
config.i18n.fallbacks.map = {}
```

Let's check:

```
...> rails console
2.7.2 :001 > I18n.fallbacks["de-AT"] # Check what happens with Austrian German?
 => [:"de-AT", :de]

2.7.2 :002 > I18n.fallbacks[:fr]     # French should have no fallback!
 => [:fr]
```

Note #2: I don't think there is a way to prevent country variants to fallback to language only locales.

Note #3: [Some more subtleties in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682715/278842)