# Avoid I18n Fallback to default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have the following configured in my *application.rb*

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:at, :de, :ch_de, :ch_fr, :fr, :int_en, :int_fr]
config.i18n.default_locale = :at
```

My default locale is set to :at (Austria). Which I require for Route Translation. Rails server won't start without it and to be fair it makes sense.

I now created a fallback map, which works just fine:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'de' => 'at', 'ch_de' => 'at', 'ch_fr' => 'fr', 'int_fr' => 'fr', 'fr' => 'fr', 'int_en' => 'int_en'}
```

So basically I want all German speaking countries to fallback on :at, whilst all French speaking countries fall back to :fr.

However, I do NOT under any circumstances want :fr to fallback on :at. This is for SEO purposes as some french pages do not have metadata configured. So now the french pages would display the Austrian :at metadata entry. Which is wrong.

If I turn of fallbacks completely:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = false
```

the following works fine in my views:

```
t('.metatitle', :default => "")
```

In that case if there is no translation available then nothing is displayed. However, the rest of the site that already exists relies on fallbacks - so this is not an option, considering the effort to implement the change.

**Is there a way turn off fallbacks for individual translations?**

**Or can I implement the fallback map and make sure that the map doesn't fallback to it's default locale if for example no french :fr translation exists?**

PS: The route translating gem that requires the default locale is [this one here](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator).

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - and thought of sharing it with you:

If you wish to avoid fallback to the default locale on individual translation you simply have to send a empty fallback array like this:

```
t('.metatitle', :default => "", :fallback => [])
```

Et Voila !

Comment: `fallback: false` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky in Rails up to 6.1 because you need to [beat the logic in the Railtie initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e300f1121dd24204cf0586521f34632485fce15/activesupport/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb#L92) which desperately wants to fallback to the `default_locale`.

To set the default fallback locale to `nil` you need to use the following code:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = "de-AT"
config.i18n.fallbacks.defaults = [[]] # If you just write [], then default_locale is used
config.i18n.fallbacks.map = {
  :de => "de-AT",
  "de-CH" => "de-AT",
}
```

Let's check:

```
$ rails console
2.7.2 :001 > I18n.fallbacks["de"]
 => [:de, :"de-AT"]
2.7.2 :002 > I18n.fallbacks["fr"]
 => [:fr]
2.7.2 :003 > I18n.fallbacks["de-CH"]
 => [:"de-CH", :de, :"de-AT"]
2.7.2 :004 > I18n.fallbacks["de-AT"]
 => [:"de-AT", :de]
2.7.2 :005 >
```

Not 100% what you want, but there just seems to be no way to prevent the fallbacks to go from country specific locale to generic language locale, when fallbacks are enabled.

Note #1: Your locales are a bit non-standard. AFAIK there is no 'at' locale, but only "de-AT".

Note #2: [Some more subtleties and notes in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682715/278842)

Comment: I admire the fact that you have given an answer to the question a few years later. I had implemented my solution 5 years ago so I went with my work around. Surprisingly the site is still up and running - so I believe it is working. Anyway, thank you for positing!!

Comment: I just needed to get to the bottom of understanding fallbacks myself. Documenting the result was the easiest part of that.